# MySQL Workbench Syntax error 1064 when creating table

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

I am completely new to both SQL and MySQL, and I've created a Schema and want to make a table. I've specified all my fields, but I find that every time it generates code, it is incorrect. This happened when I previously tried to make my schema, but I was able to fix it. However, this time around I'm completely lost.

Here's my visual layout, the generated code, then the error log:
[image: visual layout]

[image: generated code]

[image]

Comment: You didn't provide an expression for the `GENERATED` column.

Comment: I think you're confusing `GENERATED` with `AUTO_INCREMENT`.

Comment: yeah 'generated always as ()' is probably not what you want, you can read the documentation here https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table-generated-columns.html

Comment: as @Barmar said you probably want auto increment. Uncheck "G" and check "AI" columns in the options. Or instead of `GENERATED ALWAYS AS ()` just put `AUTO_INCREMENT`

Comment: thanks! I changed GENERATED to AUTO_INCREMENT, but now i'm getting this error: ERROR 1170: BLOB/TEXT column 'email' used in key specification without a key length

Comment: also, I'm not sure why you're using tinytext for email and other text related fields, try using VARCHAR and specify the length of the string expected. That should fix it.

Comment: @Dray sorry, I just chose that because I don't think it would pass 225 characters haha. is the length of the VARCHAR for the maximum? or does each entry have to specifically be that amount?

Comment: @AngelaC the length is maximum. for example you can write VARCHAR(250) for email and that will cover all the emails lower than and equal to count to 250.

Comment: thank you all! the problem has been fixed. really appreciate it!

Comment: have fun learning! @AngelaC